# GlassFish server fails to launch from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am trying to test my web application in GlassFish 4 from eclipse. When I am starting GlassFish 4 with a file (startserv.bat), it works fine, but when I am trying to run it from Eclipse, it starts loading, but then the startup process gets stuck at 69%. It is not any errors in the log. I use eclipse mars 2

Comment: maybe there is an instance already running?

Comment: How to check it. When I enter the browser localhost: 4848 Page not found